# How do I download a file from a GitHub draft

Tags: github, github-api, appveyor

I am using AppVeyor to set up the CI for a GitHub repository and upload the build artifacts to a draft named *CI builds*. The file is e.g. located under

```
https://github.com/an_organisation/a_project/releases/tag/untagged-1111aaaacccc0000dddd/filename.tar.gz
```

and can be accessed and downloaded from a browser.

Now I would like to access those uploaded artifact from another AppVeyor project (i.e. an appveyor.yml script). I tried without success to download with AppVeyor `DownloadFile` command, `curl`, and `wget` using the following commands

```
  set DOWNLOAD_FILENAME=filename.tar.gz
  set DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS=https://github.com/an_organisation/a_project/releases/download/untagged-1111aaaacccc0000dddd/$DOWNLOAD_FILENAME

  wget --header "Authorization: token $GH_AUTH_TOKEN" --output-document=$DOWNLOAD_FILENAME $DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS

  wget --auth-no-challenge --header "Accept:application/octet-stream" --output-document=$DOWNLOAD_FILENAME "$DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS?access_token:$GH_AUTH_TOKEN"

  curl -fsSL -G --user "$APPVEYOR_ACCOUNT_NAME:$GH_AUTH_TOKEN" -o $DOWNLOAD_FILENAME $DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS

  curl -fsSL -G -H "Authorization: token $GH_AUTH_TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/octet-stream" -o $DOWNLOAD_FILENAME $DOWNLOAD_ADDRESS

  curl -fsSL -G -H "Authorization: token $GH_AUTH_TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/octet-stream" -o $DOWNLOAD_FILENAME https://api.github.com/repos/an_organisation/a_project/releases/download/untagged-1111aaaacccc0000dddd/
```

Slowly I get a feeling that a file download from a draft via GitHub API or download link is not possible.

What is the correct command to download such a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR** Use the [Get Release asset API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset) with header `Accept: application/octet-stream` :

```bash
curl -OJ -L -H "Accept: application/octet-stream" \
    -H "Authorization: Token $YOUR_TOKEN" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/releases/assets/$ASSET_ID"
```

---

You need to have the assetID. In order to have it you need the releaseID if you have not already this information use [`GET /repos/:user/:repo/releases`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository) :

```bash
curl -s -H "Authorization: Token $YOUR_TOKEN" \
   "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/releases" | jq '.[] | {(.name): .id}'
```

Then get the assets IDs use [`GET /repos/:user/:repo/releases/:release_id`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release) :

```bash
curl -s -H "Authorization: Token $YOUR_TOKEN" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/releases/$RELEASE_ID" | \
    jq -r '.assets[] | {(.id |tostring): .name}'
```

Then once you have assetID (maybe you already had it btw) you can finally use [`GET /repos/:user/:repo/releases/assets/:asset_id`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset) with header `Accept: application/octet-stream`. From [the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset) :

> To download the asset's binary content, set the Accept header of the
>   request to application/octet-stream. The API will either redirect the
>   client to the location, or stream it directly if possible. API clients
>   should handle both a 200 or 302 response.

The following download the file locally :

```bash
curl -OJ -L -H "Accept: application/octet-stream" \
    -H "Authorization: Token $YOUR_TOKEN" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/releases/assets/$ASSET_ID"
```